# WPF Editable Listview with an editable ComboBox

Tags: wpf, xaml, listview, gridview

I'm trying to create a ListView with editable cells, say when I double click on a cell it turns into an editable ComboBox, I can then type something or select from the comboItems. Before I double click on a cell to edit I wouldn't wish to see the comboBox Arrow (A cell shouldnt present itself as a combobox before I am on edit mode, but as Label/TextBlock).

What I have done so far is this :

```
<GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
            <ComboBox IsEditable="True" SelectedIndex="0" >
                <ComboBoxItem>One</ComboBoxItem>
                <ComboBoxItem>Two</ComboBoxItem>
                <ComboBoxItem>Three</ComboBoxItem>
            </ComboBox>
    </DataTemplate>
</GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
```

But I can still see the ComboBox Arrow before getting in edit mode (I simply dont know how to hide the Arrow) also there is a difference in color between the ListView's selected row and the ComboBox, see:

[image]

Would you please help with sample codes, pointers or ideas. Thanks in advance.

PS: Am a beginner in WPF

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [DataGrid](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid(v=vs.110).aspx) (not ListView-GridView) with [DataGridTemplateColumn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridtemplatecolumn%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and specify different templates for display and edit modes (using your static example):

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn>
    <!-- display mode template -->
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="One" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>

    <!-- edit mode template -->
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ComboBox IsEditable="True" SelectedIndex="0" >
                <ComboBoxItem>One</ComboBoxItem>
                <ComboBoxItem>Two</ComboBoxItem>
                <ComboBoxItem>Three</ComboBoxItem>
            </ComboBox>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

---

In reality, you'd want to bind your data so your ComboBox actually selects something and TextBox displays that selection:

```
 <DataGridTemplateColumn>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding SelectedNumber}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ComboBox IsEditable="True" SelectedIndex="0" 
                      ItemsSource="{Binding Numbers}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedNumber}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use two different templates one normal and other for editing. And show/hide either.

You can build upon this approach further.

```
        <ListView.Resources>
            <DataTemplate x:Key="Tmpl1">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" GotFocus="TextBlock_GotFocus" MouseDown="TextBlock_MouseDown_1"/>
            </DataTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:Key="Tmpl2">
                <ComboBox LostFocus="ComboBox_LostFocus_1"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.Resources>
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Name" CellTemplate="{StaticResource Tmpl1}"/>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
```

Code :

```
private void TextBlock_MouseDown_1(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    ((GridView)ListView1.View).Columns[0].CellTemplate = (DataTemplate)ListView1.FindResource("Tmpl2");
}

private void ComboBox_LostFocus_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ((GridView)ListView1.View).Columns[0].CellTemplate = (DataTemplate)ListView1.FindResource("Tmpl1");
}
```